# Could not parse git.exe version number

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I keep getting a popup in TortoiseGit: "Could not parse git.exe version number." when ever I try to do anything... I have setup git 1.8 and linked it (through settings) into TortoiseGit but it's being painful.... I have the exact same versions of git/TortoiseGit on my laptop (also windows) and it worked fine with no problems =.= my windows is a fresh install too.

Comment: Could you give the output of git --version? Is it `git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0` Could you post screenshot of TortoiseGit settings general page?

Comment: here's the git --version: http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/1581/gitversion.png and I installed using: msysGit-fullinstall-1.8.0-preview20121022.exe and TortoiseGit-1.7.14.0-64bit.msi

Comment: In TortoiseGit settings page, set git.exe path `C:\msysgit\git`,set external DLL path `C:\msysgit\mingw\bin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the path to git.exe is C:\msysgit\msysgit\bin\git.exe then you have to enter C:\msysgit\msysgit\bin as git.exe path and C:\msysgit\msysgit\mingw\bin into "Extern DLL Path" (because otherwise some mingw dll can't be found).

If this doesn't help, [please see here](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1533)

Answer (score 3):

If none of the solution above works, try disabling your firewall.

I had this problem as well and I tried the solutions posted here and here https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1533

But nothing worked until I disabled my firewall.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: This helped me, disabled Comodo sandbox and now it is working fine. Issue appeared after upgrading msysgit. I also had other issues (unix tools crashes) when running Comodo sandbox.

Comment: Same here. Comodo was silently sandboxing tartoiseSVN, and I had to whitelist it before everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding double quotes to both fields fixed it for me after I followed Sven's instructions above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, so here's what I did:

1. Rightclick -> Tortoise Git -> Settings
2. General
3. For Extern DLL Path, type **Path\To\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext64.dll**

After doing this, Tortoise Git started working flawlessly. It updated Git.exe Path to: **Path\To\Git\bin**

No more unsightly errors, no more messages talking about Git source being at code.google.com or whatever that was ... everything worked flawlessly for me.

Hope this solves your problem :D

**Edit**

It should go without saying that \path\to\ is a common understanding amongst programmers, but I'd rather be safe than sorry by clarifying what I mean.

My \path\to\ for git is: **C:\Program Files (x86)**

This means that my Git.exe Path is: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin** and my Extern DLL Path is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext64.dll**.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and noticed that the v1.8.0 Git for Windows installer will install to the local user's AppData folder if it is not launched with administrative privileges. While it's great to be able to install the application as a standard user, this behaviour is subtle and is inconsistent with other MSI style installers.

I uninstalled Git from AppData and re-ran the same Git for Windows installer *as administrator*, and the error message no longer appeared in Tortoise Git. This is probably because Git was now installed in the expected location (which on my 64 bit machine was C:\Program Files (x86)\Git).

I installed the following versions:

- Tortoise Git 1.8.0.0 64-bit
- Git 1.8.0 preview 20121022

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to run Tortoise Git Settings as an administrator, then set the paths according to Sven's answer and then I clicked "Check now". After closing the settings window everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This is unbelievable. I tried everything here with no effect. Then I:
- copied git.exe to c:/
- entered the path to git.exe: c:
Now the error message changed.
- re-entered proper path to git.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
- entered the external path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah"

And Git was recognized!

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, none of the suggested solutions worked. I deactivated COMODO Sandbox for a while, did a clone via the tortoiseGit context menu, worked. After reboot the Sandbox was reactivated, So adding it to the trusted programs worked permanently. Thanks!. Thought I share it here too.